# What else do you need to change when changing JSP file names

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I recently coded a simple login system using JSP -> servlet -> SQL method with Eclipse and Tomcat v8.5. Everything was working until I changed the name of my jsp files under the web content folder. **I initially had my intial jsp file as Login.jsp and then changed it to login.jsp.** I also edited the  in web.xml from Login.jsp to login.jsp.

Upon running, I encountered the HTTP Status 404 - Not Found with the description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Do you have any suggestions what settings should I also change to make it work again?

Answer (score 0):

It works now! I removed the project from the tomcat server then refreshed the project then added it back. Thanks!